# Word describing the feeling of being lazy about doing something

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In my language we can express the feeling of not willing to do something because we feel lazy about it. Is there any word in english that allows us to express this feeling?

Comment: "Unmotivated", perhaps?

Comment: Single? Unemployed? Human? [Enui](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enui)?

Comment: I feel indolent about answering this question. So I won't.

Comment: Oh I just realized that you answered my question. First when I read it I thought it was rude :D sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Maybe *apathetic* or *lethargic*.

Comment: Could you expand on this a bit - do you have references, definitions or examples that support your suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The word I feel that is best fit for this would be:

> [**Lackadaisical**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lackadaisical)
>
> 1. without interest, vigor, or determination; listless; lethargic:
>
> *a lackadaisical attempt.*
>
> 2. lazy; indolent:
>
> *a lackadaisical fellow.*

Converting to a noun would be **lackadaisicalness**.

Comment: What's the source of this definition? I've always thought it described the *way* a task is performed, rather than the unwillingness to do so (as described in the question).

Answer (score 1):

A **lazy streak** maybe?

> *Sixteen weird things you do when you're going through a lazy streak.* ([**Thought Catalog**](http://thoughtcatalog.com/jamie-varon/2015/03/no-pants-allowed/))
>
> *There are many ways you can get yourself into a streak of laziness.* ([**Pick the Brain**](http://www.pickthebrain.com/blog/laziness/))
>
> **streak**: (*Informal*) A brief run or stretch, as of luck.
> ([**American Heritage® Dictionary**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/streak))

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question, ***unmotivated*** appears to be the closest match. [From Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/motivate):

> **motivate**
>   *verb*
>
> 1. to give (someone) a reason for doing something
> 2. to be a reason for (something)

*Motivated*, the adjective form of *motivate* would simply inherit the definition of *motivate* in passive form, i.e. *given a reason for doing something*. So *unmotivated* would be *not given a reason [or sufficient reason] for doing something*. We're naturally lazy unless we are motivated to overcome that laziness.

Other options with differing nuances are ***reluctant***, ***unenthusiastic***, or ***uninterested***, depending on the context. But ***unmotivated*** is about the closest I can think of.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.  We generally expect answers to provide supporting rationale.  This may take the form of quoted definitions from dictionaries and a statement or two about why that particular word and definition fits the OP situation.

Comment: Sure thing, I've updated my answer.